# how can we prepare dataset from ocr text data for deep learning model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have tried for convert receipt image to text and its code is here below-
in python 2.7.

Code :-

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import image_to_string

image = Image.open('/home/deepak/Documents/BRVm15K.jpg',mode='r')
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(image,lang="en")
print(txt)
```

Output what i got :-

> office supply hut
>   Date/Time: 2009-08-29 10:32 AM
>
> NYC DCA EL#1371013 EHASD#I47ZBB
>   Cashier: Sam
>
> OTY ITEM
>
> 1 GLUE STICK CLEARANCE 1.99
>   0476432068904
>
> 1 ROTARY CARD FILE 25.95
>   4329323455094
>
> 1 MAXLIFE CYAN TONER @ 18.49 ea
>   5422636437387 18 . 49
>
> 1 MAXLIFE DESKTOP LASERJET
>   2342897237346 149 .67
>
> SUBTOTAL 197 . 10
>
> Tax 18 . 31
>
> TOTAL $215.41

I want to extract information of interest like as organisation name,date,description,total amount from text data after **ocr** using pytesseract method.

i have completed task of **image to text** data from an **image of receipt**.so my requirement for data-set & how can i prepare data-set for deep learning training model?

Comment: Parse the data by yourself? e.g.: date is always on the first line after ':'

Comment: I would suggest writing your output to a file rather than `print(txt)` , then parsing through that file line by line looking for the information you mentioned (organization, date, total etc.) Things like date's and total price should be relatively easy to parse out (using regex to match different dates or to look for $$ amounts). Organization name and descriptions may be trickier, mostly because it will be hard to tell what information is actually useful and what is just noise because all receipts will not share the same format. Search youtube/google for building an OCR pipeline to get an idea

Comment: Thanks @NathanBlaine for your suggestion but i have already parsed date and total price using regex now i want to prepare data for deep learning model in which data train and will give desired output that is org name,date,total,description.so can you help me for data preparing for this model? – deepak patidar 2 hours ago